# Hyperledger fabric on AWS, peers get crash after anchor peer update

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have deployed hyperledger fabric on aws ec2 instances.

```
peer0.sales.billerxchange.com (ec2 instance 1)
peer1.sales.billerxchange.com (ec2 instance 2)
peer0.employee.billerxchange.com (ec2 instance 3)
peer1.employee.billerxchange.com (ec2 instance 4)
ca.sales.billerxchange.com (ec2 instance 5)
ca.employee.billerxchange.com (ec2 instance 6)
orderer.billerxchange.com (ec2 instance 7)
```

all peers,ca and orderer are deployed on seperate instances and managed by docker swarm and deployed on docker overlay network.
i'm able join channel but when i try updating anchor peer in channel

```
peer channel update -c settlement -o orderer.billerxchange.com:7050 -f billerxchangepeer.tx
```

i updated peer0 as anchor peer peer0 will get update and all the other peers in the network will crash. only peer0 remains up rest all peer containers are stopped or exited. I've attached container logs please check.

```
    2018-09-28 20:14:58.041 UTC [gossip/gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 032 Learning about the configured anchor peers of BillerXchange for channel settlement : [{peer0.sales.billerxchange.com 7051}]
2018-09-28 20:14:58.042 UTC [committer/txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 033 [settlement] Validated block [1] in 5ms
2018-09-28 20:14:58.046 UTC [gossip/state] commitBlock -> ERRO 034 Got error while committing(unexpected Previous block hash. Expected PreviousHash = [20c677285adc8bb6ecaa08d07f4b56038f1eb646a1e2c46c4915716772ac622b], PreviousHash referred in the latest block= [4abc11f19eed89a96d1fd6280512cea1504c1ff202e4f0d0cc5ad1945648343a]
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage.(*blockfileMgr).addBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage/blockfile_mgr.go:254
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage.(*fsBlockStore).AddBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage/fs_blockstore.go:43
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgerstorage.(*Store).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgerstorage/store.go:124
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.(*kvLedger).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/kv_ledger.go:271
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.(*closableLedger).CommitWithPvtData
    <autogenerated>:1
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/committer.(*LedgerCommitter).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/committer/committer_impl.go:93
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata.(*coordinator).StoreBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata/coordinator.go:229
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).commitBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:771
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:558
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
commit failed
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata.(*coordinator).StoreBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata/coordinator.go:231
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).commitBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:771
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:558
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).commitBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:772
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:558
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361)
2018-09-28 20:14:58.046 UTC [gossip/state] deliverPayloads -> PANI 035 Cannot commit block to the ledger due to unexpected Previous block hash. Expected PreviousHash = [20c677285adc8bb6ecaa08d07f4b56038f1eb646a1e2c46c4915716772ac622b], PreviousHash referred in the latest block= [4abc11f19eed89a96d1fd6280512cea1504c1ff202e4f0d0cc5ad1945648343a]
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage.(*blockfileMgr).addBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage/blockfile_mgr.go:254
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage.(*fsBlockStore).AddBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage/fs_blockstore.go:43
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgerstorage.(*Store).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgerstorage/store.go:124
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.(*kvLedger).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/kv_ledger.go:271
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.(*closableLedger).CommitWithPvtData
    <autogenerated>:1
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/committer.(*LedgerCommitter).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/committer/committer_impl.go:93
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata.(*coordinator).StoreBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata/coordinator.go:229
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).commitBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:771
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:558
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
commit failed
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata.(*coordinator).StoreBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata/coordinator.go:231
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).commitBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:771
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:558
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:563
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
panic: Cannot commit block to the ledger due to unexpected Previous block hash. Expected PreviousHash = [20c677285adc8bb6ecaa08d07f4b56038f1eb646a1e2c46c4915716772ac622b], PreviousHash referred in the latest block= [4abc11f19eed89a96d1fd6280512cea1504c1ff202e4f0d0cc5ad1945648343a]
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage.(*blockfileMgr).addBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage/blockfile_mgr.go:254
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage.(*fsBlockStore).AddBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage/fs_blockstore.go:43
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgerstorage.(*Store).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgerstorage/store.go:124
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.(*kvLedger).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/kv_ledger.go:271
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.(*closableLedger).CommitWithPvtData
    <autogenerated>:1
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/committer.(*LedgerCommitter).CommitWithPvtData
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/committer/committer_impl.go:93
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata.(*coordinator).StoreBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata/coordinator.go:229
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).commitBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:771
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:558
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
commit failed
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata.(*coordinator).StoreBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/privdata/coordinator.go:231
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).commitBlock
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:771
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:558
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:563
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361

goroutine 696 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc4202d00b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x4f4
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc42000e4d8, 0x4, 0x1113a7d, 0x2c, 0xc422400dd0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc42000e4d8, 0x1113a7d, 0x2c, 0xc422400dd0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc42000e4e0, 0x1113a7d, 0x2c, 0xc422400dd0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.(*GossipStateProviderImpl).deliverPayloads(0xc420173980)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:563 +0x4af
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state.NewGossipStateProvider
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/state/state.go:239 +0x699
```

Comment: please open a JIRA in http://jira.hyperledger.org/

Comment: and tag me in it, OK ? same username as here.

Comment: I suspect the peers that crashed have joined the channel with a different genesis block (block 0). Perhaps you had a prior trial with a different genesis block? And then when the peers get block 1 from orderer, the prior block hash doesn't match the hash of their block 0. And only peer0 has the correct genesis block that matches up with block 1 prior hash. Could you test that theory?

Comment: @DaveEnyeart  thanks, definitely its a problem of  genesis block i tried bringing down whole network  and build it again from scratch and now it works fine. but i am not able to figure out how it happened because i copied same configuration on all instances might be i would have missed something. any ways now it works good.

Comment: @yacovm. thanks i figured out.

Comment: can you help me in resolving warning continuously showing up on orderer.

    2018-09-29 19:30:26.053 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 00d Error reading from 10.0.0.11:34086: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2018-09-29 19:32:31.857 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 00e Error reading from 10.0.0.8:58396: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2018-09-29 19:32:31.864 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 00f Error reading from 10.0.0.8:58398: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

Comment: You kept us in suspense all day! 
And the error from the orderer log is due to clients disconnecting abruptly. I guess you're using peer CLI... you can check live if the time the peer CLI is used correlates to the time these warnings appear in the logs

Comment: @yacovm apologies for late response, but can you help me in understanding how is it possible that all the peers are able to join channel if they are having incorrect block info.only peer0 had correct block info. as i created channel from peer0 and join it even other peers were able to fetch block and join channel they were only crashing if i try to update anchor peer or install chaincode on peer0. as per my understanding when we create channel and join it 1st block is created so with incorrect block info other peer should not be able to join channel.

Comment: If the block is "similar" enough (same channel ID, more or less similar certificates) then it'd work... but the block hash would be different.

Comment: Ok got it,so peer with similar block info except hash are able to join and create blocks  but they are not able to commit any block to ledger and thats why all the peers with invalid block info get crashed at same time while commiting blocks to ledger.